# onsubmit="function()" is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, onsubmit

I want to validate the dynamically added fields of the form(present in the templates/appname) in django. I am adding those fields with the help of the javascript (**addInput.js** - stored at a place mentioned as source in the script tag) which also has the logics for removing those fields as well as validating those fields values. But when I click send_invites button, it directs me again to app/register when I **first** want that it should go to the `validateEmail()` function if everything is fine **then** it should **redirect to app/register.**

```js
    var counter = 1;
    var limit = 5;

    function addInput(divName) {

      if (counter == limit) {

        alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " Email Addresses");

      } else {

        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = "<p id = 'remove" + counter + "'>Email Address " + (counter + 1) + " : " + "<input type = 'text' name ='myInputs[]'></p>";
        document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
        counter++;
        alert(counter + "add");
      }
    }

    function removeInput(divName) {

      if (counter == 1) {

        alert("You have reached the limit of removing Email Addresses");

      } else {
        counter--;
        var olddiv = document.getElementById("remove" + counter);
        alert(counter + "remove");
        olddiv.parentNode.removeChild(olddiv);

      }
    }

    function validateEmail(divName) {

      var emailFilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

      console.log("cmn");
      alert("cmn");
      for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {

        var email = $("#remove" + i).val();

        alert(email);
        //      return true;

      }
      return true;

    }
```

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <br>

      <h1 class="page-header">
        Send Invites
        </h1>

      <form method="POST" onsubmit="return validateEmail('dynamicInput')" action="/app/register/">
        <div id="dynamicInput">
          <p id='remove0'>Email Address 1 :
            <input type="text" name="myInputs[]">
          </p>

        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Add another Email Address" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
        <input type="button" value="Remove Email Address Field " onClick="removeInput('dynamicInput');">

        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send Invites">
        <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='xyz' />
      </form>

      <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
  </div>
  <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->
</div>
<style>
  a.active {
    background-color: #eee;
  }
</style>
```

But why is this not happening? other two javascript functions addInput and removeInput are working fine. Only validateEmail is not getting called, for which I am even calling alert and console.log but nothing is getting displayed. Please help. I am new to javascript.

Comment: I can't imagine what any of this has to do with Django.

Comment: well your JS is not valid above so hard to figure out what the add code is doing. Any errors in the console? Did you set up the console to preserve the log on navigation?

Comment: @epascarello : what is there that makes you feel that JS is not valid ?

Comment: @epascarello : I have been able to run other two functions perfectly

Comment: The code above is not complete....The one line is missing half the code. You can tell by looking at the coloring of the text in the JS block. It is all brown because of the issue. The line with `newdiv.innerHTML ` is wrong.

Comment: @epascarello : now can you please look at it ? I have edited the post, it was copy paste error, by the way thanks for pointing out  !!

Comment: Your regex is all wrong! what do you want it to do? just `x@x.co` or you have minimam chars restrictions in emails, such as before and after `@` etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the code, clicking the button, you get the following error in the console.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:
>   /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/:
>   Unterminated group

Looking at the code you have an extra (

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
                    ^
```

So you are either missing a closing `)` or you have the extra `(`. My guess is you are missing a `)` before the `+`. Look at wherever you found the reg exp and see what it should be.